# Jasper Group Header band spilling over to second page

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I have encountered a challenging problem using Jasper reports.  I currently have a table defined by a Group Header, followed by a Detail band, which itself is followed by a Group Footer.  Inside the Group Footer I have included a textField with isStretchWithOverflow="true" for that field.  The contents of this textField can be very large, forcing a spillover to the next page.

The predicament I have is that the Group Header is also being displayed on the next page, even though there is no table or line items.  This looks highly awkward as there is a table header with no following table.

From what I can gather, Jasper is rendering the Group Header on the next page because the Group Footer is present there.  In other words, it appears that if the Group Footer is present, the Group Header will be printed even if the details band has already been rendered on a previous page.

Group 1 HEADER
Group 1 DETAIL 1
Group 1 DETAIL 2
...
Group 1 DETAIL n
Group 1 FOOTER (beginning of Group 1 FOOTER)

<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<-PAGE BREAK

Group 1 HEADER (but there is no table here!!!)

Group 1 FOOTER (remainder of Group 1 FOOTER from the previous page)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check these two properties of the group header:

1. Group Expression: It should be null.
2. Reprint header: false

Comment: Your suggestion solves the above problem but creates another one.  When setting isReprintHeaderOnEachPage="true" is does prevent the group header from appearing on the subsequent page.  However, it ALWAYS does not appear on the second page, even when there IS a table there with line items.

Comment: Table should appear on the second page also, just check the property of table "Print When Group Changes", do not select any group.

Comment: Tables appear on the second page, but the header is missing.  It seems Jasper insists on printing a Group Header on a page if a Group Footer is also present.